# Using data-filter with its position fixed (non-scrollable)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQueryMobile for a small project of mine. When displaying a listview plus its search filter with 1000 thousand items, I realized it would be better to keep the search input box fixed while scrolling the list, just as the header is.
Imagine that what I have is:

```
<section data-role="page" id="start-page">
  <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Start Page!</h1>
  </header>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="start-page-listview" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." data-filter-theme="d" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d"></ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

What is the best for achieving this? Is there a way to do it without having to touch jQuery Mobile files (css or js) themselves?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

put the search field in the header and data-position is fixed

```
<section data-role="page" id="start-page">
 <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
   <h1>Start Page!</h1>
   <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="start-page-listview" data-filter-  placeholder="Search..." data-filter-theme="d" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d"></ul>
 </header>
 <div data-role="content">

</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work and it broke the layout of the page entirely. The listview wasn't even scrollable anymore.